# How to set background-position value in sprite sheet animation?

Tags: html, css, animation

I have written this code:

```css
body {
  background: #24aecd;
}

#monster {
  width: 190px;
  height: 290px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  background: url('http://treehouse-code-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/CSS-DD/codepen/blog/monster.png') left center;
  animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
}

@keyframes play {
  100% {
    background-position: -1900px;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="monster"></div>
</body>
```

It is working properly But when I change the background-position it doesn't work properly.

> Can anyone explain how to set background-position value in different
>   sprit sheets.

How could

Comment: can you explain or show, what exactly you want? For us it's animated and looks good. You haven't mentioned what output you are expecting.

Comment: if you add `background-repeat: no-repeat;` this looks perfect to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"But when I change the background-position it doesn't work properly." -- The `background-position` in `play` keyframes should NOT be changed in your case, the value 1900px is exactly the width of background image. Here is the explanation for the whole animation:

1. The animation is implemented by one big background image (http://treehouse-code-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/CSS-DD/codepen/blog/monster.png). If you download and open this image, it is composed by 10 separate small images (horizontally), each one contributes to 1 frame in the animation.
2. By default, the most left frame image is displayed (`left` in the `#monster`'s `background` property).
3. An animation is defined, using 10 frames and 0.8s period, which is played infinitely. The effect of animation is moving the background image left, one frame image per step (-1900px / 10 = -190px, 190px is the width of one frame image). After all 10 frame images are displayed, the `background-position` would be -1900px (`100%` in keyframes) and new round would begin, as the background image is repeated.

`background-repeat-x` is necessary for this animation, otherwise it could not be animated infinitely. However, `background-repeat-y` should be `no-repeat` for better effect.

If you want to change the animated background image, and change corresponding `background-position`, similar calculation can be applied -- separate frames, composed into one image, set `100%` keyframes as the negative width of the composed image, and finally define CSS animation.

UPDATE:

As for the example sprite image mentioned in comments, its width is 612px and composed by 6 frames, thus the width of one frame is 102px. The code snippet would be:

```css
#monster {
  width: 102px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/hCmcllpdGXPzzIkEQxUf8EEkl2Tc9WqLu4D9JIAbPtmLpb5Fx0H7DG2yojnZ-rRNt8XXsM-xBGEWrPijzLnVZUpZbAnWTNui9TLjwdzm2R_PFdwwhVh0jV0=w612-h148-nc') left center;
  animation: play .8s steps(6) infinite;
  background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes play {
  100% {
    background-position: -612px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="monster"></div>
```

Comment: First of all I will like to thanks you.You mean I have to  multiply the width of the one image with the number of images inn sprite sheet and then I have to write that number in background-position as negative. If yes please tell how can I know the width of an image

Comment: @rohitsingh For image of one single frame, If it is an existed image, I think you can use any image viewer/editor to check its size. If you need to make it yourself, the width depends on how large you want to show the animation.

Comment: U didn't replied to my first question

Comment: Background-position: -(width of one frame *no.of frames). Am I right??

Comment: Plz suggest one image viewer

Comment: @rohitsingh sorry that I missed it. Yes, you can define the calculated negative value as the `background-position` of `100%` keyframe.

Comment: hmmm, actually I think you can just check image file's property (right click the file and view its property) and Windows/Mac will tell you its width&height.

Comment: When I am far from my computer I used my android  device to code. So In android which app or how

Comment: @rohitsingh In my Android device (Xiaomi), I can see image's resolution by checking its property information (just use Android system, no third-party App needed). But things may go differently in other Android devices.

Comment: I got the width of the sprite sheet I was wanting but then also it doesn't animate

Comment: I got the width of the sprite sheet I was wanting but then also it doesn't animate. [  https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/hCmcllpdGXPzzIkEQxUf8EEkl2Tc9WqLu4D9JIAbPtmLpb5Fx0H7DG2yojnZ-rRNt8XXsM-xBGEWrPijzLnVZUpZbAnWTNui9TLjwdzm2R_PFdwwhVh0jV0=w612-h148-nc] this is link of the sprite sheet please can u tell me what background position should I write for it. plz tell me the background position of sprite sheet in the link.

Comment: @rohitsingh I've edited my answer and attached code snippet for your sprite image.

Comment: @rohitsingh Is your problem solved? If yes, maybe you can "accept" this answer?

Answer (score 0):

The height of your monster should be 240px, not 290px.

```css
body {
  background: #24aecd;
}

#monster {
  width: 190px;
  height: 240px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  background: url('http://treehouse-code-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/CSS-DD/codepen/blog/monster.png') left center;
  animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
}

@keyframes play {
  100% {
    background-position: -1900px;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="monster"></div>
</body>
```